# jQuery sent URL request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

In my page i want to send a jQuery request to another PHP script, without reloading the whole page.
When clicking a button, the request needs to be sent to another PHP script, through POST.
I just can't get it to work. My code so far:

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#pause').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // preventing default click action
        $.ajax({
            url: '/cura/includes/pause_agent.inc.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: $pausedata,
            success: function(){
                // ajax callback
            }, error: function(){
                alert('ajax failed');
            },
        })
    })
})
</script>
```

PHP code of button & URL to be sent:

```
        if($member['Paused']==0){
        $pausedata = '?action=agentpause&agent='.$member['Location'].'&paused=true';
    echo('<td><button id="pause" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Pause&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</button></td>');
}
else{
    $pausedata = '?action=agentpause&agent='.$member['Location'].'&paused=false';
echo('<td><button id="pause" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Unpause</button></td>');    
}
```

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: `data: $pausedata` ????

Comment: who is $pausedata ??

Comment: $pausedata this is perhaps a PHP variable. you cannot use it in ajax request the way you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things to note here, first of all you need to make sure your document is ready before doing your jQuery, to do this you can either put your script at the bottom of the page or put all of your script inside a

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {}
```

event.

To post data there is a shortcut which is

```
$.post("path/to/php/script.php", 
      {postVariableOne:valueOne, postVariableTwo:valueTwo,...},
      function(data){
       //callback function
      });
```

Note `valueOne` and `valueTwo` are javascript variables

Then, in the PHP script, you would access the sent data like this

```
$_POST['postVariableOne'];//this equals valueOne
```